# Does Old Swedish dictionary exist?

Tags: swedish

Does Old Swedish dictionary exist?

Comment: It is generally recommended that you describe any research that you've done, and what the results are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [online one](https://spraakbanken.gu.se/fsvldb/), based on the dictionaries of Söderwall and Schlyter cited [here](https://spraakbanken.gu.se/fsvldb/index2.html).